# Redirect HTTP to external HTTPS without URL change

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ssl

I have a web application where every customer get it's own subdomain, e.g. `customer.domanA.com`

To allow customers to use their own domain we offer them the possibility to send us a SSL certificate for their domain and we configure our app to listen to the customers domain. The SSL certificate is needed to run the app.

One customer now has the problem, that he does not have a certificate for his subdomain, only for his root domain. So he ask me if it is possible to use a transparent redirect of one of his domains subfolder (e.g. `customerdomain.com/app`) to our app, but without changing the URL in the users browser.

I think about a redirect rule with apaches `mod_redirect` via `.htaccess`. But is it even possible to redirect the user to another domain without changing the URL and showing a valid SSL certificate?

I have tried to add the .htaccess to the folder but it does not work correctly:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://customer.domain.com/1 [P] 
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Mod proxy should be enable to working with [P] flag.

Comment: see this relative question https://serverfault.com/questions/84821/apache-proxypass-with-ssl